# ROS Camera Calibration for Webcam - Not working

Tags: cameras, calibration

As a part of learning, I am trying to perform Camera calibration with my laptop's Webcam. I am really new to this process. I will explain everything about how far I have come so far, and where I have issues in coming to an successful calibration.

My system specifications: Ubuntu 18.04, ROS Melodic.

For Camera streaming, I am using usb_cam ros package http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam. And it is working perfectly fine.

After I launch the usb_cam-test.launch, I looked into the rostopic list, where I could find the following two topics: /usb_cam/image_raw /usb_cam/camera_info

So, I progressed forward to perform the camera calibration with the ros package "camera_calibration", but instead of getting a camera stream with calibration options as given in the tutorials, I get a black screen like below:

https://user-images.githubusercontent...

This calibration task is crucial to perform a task at my work. So, I would really need to get some help from someone who has been through this issue before. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Sorry, the link doesn't work. Link for the included picture in the post: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22639337/130369027-429f2091-f2b7-466f-a6f5-b0d2725f55c8.png

Comment: In your screenshot, seems you encounter an error. Did you have take a look at that error?